# Does a topological charge always need to be an integer

Tags: topology, topological-order, topological-phase

Does a topological charge always need to be an integer, I see many papers where people talk about non-integer topological charges due to boundary conditions. According to the formula for the topological charge; topological charge can be finite even if the spin direction inside and outside the core are different but then Q won't be an integer. But merons with half-integer topological charges also exist
I understand if we think in terms of just mathematical Chern numbers etc then non-integral values don't make any sense.
If I understand correctly the Skryme conditions are fulfilled only in terms of infinite boundary conditions.
Please let me know.